# Removing a comma at end a each row in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the below dataframe

[image]

After doing the below manipulations to the dataframe, I am getting the output in the Rule column with comma at the end which is expected .but I want to remove it .How to do it

```
df['Rule'] = df.State.apply(lambda x: str("'"+str(x)+"',"))
df['Rule'] = df.groupby(['Description'])['Rule'].transform(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
df1 = df.drop_duplicates('Description',keep = 'first')
df1['Rule'] = df1['Rule'].apply(lambda x: str("("+str(x)+")")
```

I have tried it using `ilo[-1].replace(",","")`. But it is not working .

Comment: Please also add the dataframe as formatted text, so users can copy-paste it easily and reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think you should use `.agg` instead of `.transform`, s.t. you don't have to `.drop_duplicates` afterwards: `df1 = df.groupby("Description", as_index=False).agg(Rule=("State", ", ".join))`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['Rule'] = df.State.apply(lambda x: str("'"+str(x)+"'"))
df['Rule'] = df.groupby(['Description'])['Rule'].transform(lambda x: ', '.join(x))
df1 = df.drop_duplicates('Description', keep = 'first')
df1['Rule'] = df1['Rule'].apply(lambda x: str("("+str(x)+")"))
```

Comment: pandas series support direct string operations (`apply` is slow and should be avoided whenever possible): `df['Rule'] = "'" + df['State'] + "'"` and `df1['Rule'] = "(" + df1['Rule'] + ")"`

Comment: Also: You don't need a `lambda` in `.transform`: `', '.join` is already a function that can be used directly (`.transform(', '.join)`).